# What are fs constants in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

What are fs constants (fs.constants) and what is its use in the `fs.access` method, as shown here? - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-access-method/

What use do they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially an enum - an object whose properties describe (and whose values uniquely identify) a particular flag or indicator used with fs. See the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_constants).

> Returns an object containing commonly used constants for file system operations.

You can use them in combination with fs operations to (reasonably) concisely and readably describe what you want to do.

For example, with the `fs.access` from your link:

> mode: It is an integer value that denotes the permission to be tested for. The logical OR operator can be used to seperate multiple permission. It can have the values `fs.constants.F_OK, fs.constants.R_OK, fs.constants.W_OK` and `fs.constants.X_OK`. It is an optional parameter. The default value is `fs.constants.F_OK`.

The *actual values* contained inside the object don't really matter (other than that they're all distinct from each other, and that they can be used with | for a bitmask).

[image]

Comment: With respect to fs.constants being an enum, what do its properties map to? if im understanding that part right

Comment: They're numbers - that's how they can be used with bitmasks - but other than that, it's not something to care about. Don't try to memorize them, just know that they're there.

Comment: OK, theyre numbers. That makes more sence. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: One other question, how come their values dont matter?

Comment: I suppose it's not so much that they don't matter, it's that it's not something a script-writer has any reason to care about, because you should only be referencing them by their properties in the `fs.constants` object.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-access-constants